# Should I create Separate EC2 for each database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-rds-data-service

I am creating one fullstack web application that will be used by different organisations (total 50+). I want to create separate database for each organisation.

Should I create separate EC2 and RDS for each organisation or what will be the best approach.

Note: Each org will have max 1000 users.

- My plan is to use AWS elastic-beanstalk.
- Frontend: Angular
- Backend: Springboot

I am seeking best cost effective and best performance solution.

Comment: Most cost effective would be least resources - so a multi tennant application that shared RDS instance(s) and EC2 instance(s) between organizations.  Whether that's less performant depends on application behavior.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A database 'server' can contain multiple logical 'databases'. Therefore, you would only need one database 'server'.

When the application connects to the database server, it would specify a 'database' via the connection string. It will then only see data in that logical database.

Here is a diagram from [Creating, Destroying, and Viewing Databases :: Chapter 3. PostgreSQL SQL Syntax and Use :: Part I: General PostgreSQL Use :: Postgresql :: SQL :: eTutorials.org](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Postgresql/Part+I+General+PostgreSQL+Use/Chapter+3.+PostgreSQL+SQL+Syntax+and+Use/Creating+Destroying+and+Viewing+Databases/) that demonstrates the concept (a 'cluster' is the database server):

[image: Database server hierarchy]

It is better to run your database on **Amazon RDS** (rather than on an Amazon EC2 instance), since it is fully-managed and is easy to make backups ('Snapshots') and to restore those backups. You can also scale the database independently to the EC2 instances.